# Explorer.exe Class not Registered

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

So hey guys, I'm in a bit of a sticky situation here. So I booted up my computer on Monday, loaded fine and everything seemed to work until i tried opening the file explorer, when boom error message.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8NLo.png)

Being an Com Sci major and having some experience with viruses and windows misbehaving, I went straight into trying to trying to fix my issue, but it wasn't as simple as i thought it would be.

Firstly i did a complete scan with Malwarebytes and it found 'Legit.BatBitRst' which is an adware trojan. Malwarebytes got rid of it and i thought my problem was solved. No it wasn't.

So i went online looking up this issue. Found that i might just need to re-register the explorerframe.dll. That didn't work either:

[2nd Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RqRI.png)

So in doing some more reading i saw were it might be some windows feature settings related to IE and Edge so i tried opening control panel:

[Control Panel Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brkz6.png)

I even tried windows update to see if that would help but when i click update and security in settings, it just quits.

I've tried sfc/scannow which said that some files are corrupted but it couldn't fix them, did the dism/online thing after which completed successfully but didn't solve the issue after running sfc/scannow again.

Doing a clean boot, or a safe boot didn't help fix the issue; and a deep administrative scan of the entire C drive, by Eset Smart Security came back clean.

So i'm at my wits end, any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Windows 10 Enterprise x64 (v. 1803)
Intel i5-3210M 2.6GHz(3.0GHz)
Nvidia GT635M 1GB
8GB RAM (7.9 usable)
700GB HDD

Comment: Things got really messed up. Clean install Windows 10.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Been trying to avoid that but i guess its my only option at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This was from a Win7x64 machine:

Tried fixing this for two days and here was what worked for me:

Control panel>Folder Options>View> Launch folder  windows in a separate process DISBALED

Goodluck!